# Paypal - How do I tie recurring payments back to a user or transaction?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-subscriptions

I'm curious how I can tie a recurring payment sent by IPN back to a given user.

Right now I just store in my database a link to MY user w/the payer ID given to me by paypal.

This works great 90% of the time, but completely fails if they create a new user account on my site (maybe to buy it for a friend), and then purchase from the same payer ID (as my solution always links to the FIRST user account, so the recurring payment gets associated w/the wrong user).

When I create the recurring profile, is there a way I can store a custom field, like user id with it?  Then when the IPN notifies me of a future recurring payment I just look it up that way vs. using the paypal payer id?

Googling didn't get me far on this one :/

Thanks in advance!
~ Josh

Comment: I think that's what the `PROFILEID` returned from `CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile` is for.

Comment: I literally had never noticed this before!  Thanks so so much!

Answer (score 0):

I see the comment above may already have solved your problem, but in case someone else has the same problem;

After a bit of a refresh of my memory, yes, the `PROFILEID` returned from `CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile` when you create the recurring payment is a unique id for the payment profile, so it's unique per *subscription*, not only per user. In other words, it's the identifier you need to solve your problem.